# Python / pandas Import data from multiple excel sheets and transpose to a single excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas, transpose

I am looking for a way in python to import data from a number of columns from a series of several 100s of excel sheets, transpose it, and export it to a new excel (see figure below to illustrate concept). I can iterate through the files, get the data but am stuck to transpose the data and write it/append it to a new dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

path =r'C:\Users\data'
filenames = glob.glob(path + "/*.xlsx")
files = os.listdir(path)

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == 'xlsx']
df = pd.DataFrame()

for f in files_xls:
    data = pd.read_excel(path+'\\'+f, 'Assessment')
    answers_to_copy =  list(range(20, 32))+list(range(33, 113))
    df = []
    Entity_Name     = data['Definition'][11]
    for ind in answers_to_copy:
        print(data['IndicatorName'][ind], data['Answer'][ind])
```

[image]

Comment: Could you give us some real example of the content in your excel file? I didn't understood the picture. You want to convert the green columns into a line header at output, and the other columns will be transposed to the other lines in output?

Comment: Look into https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/reshaping.html

Comment: @HenriqueBranco you are correct: the green cells represent a header which is equal in each file; and the other colors are unique values that need to be transposed and copied as rows/lines. Also note that not the entire column is copied (so only a certain range of cells). This makes the solution by Brendan a bit more difficult I think because pivoting the data would be applied to the entire row

Comment: Try to search for the `openpyxl` library, in substitution to `pandas`. It's easier to work when you are dealing with excel's cells copy and paste.